# Equation of Normal?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I got a question that I need help on:

Q1: The curve C has the equation $2x+3y^2+3x^2y=4x^2$.
The point P on the curve has coordinates $(-1,1).$

(a): Find the gradient of the curve at P.

So I did: $\frac{d}{dx}(2x+3y^2+3x^2y=4x^2$

$2+6y\frac{dy}{dx}+6xy+3x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=8x$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{8x-2}{6y+6xy}$

Using the coordinates (-1,1)

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}$

Q2: Hence find the equation of the normal to curve C at P, giving your answer in the form of $ax+by+c=0$.

I just don't understand what they want me to do, "normal to the curve C at P?"

Comment: Is your question “what does ‘normal to the curve’ mean?” or “how do I compute the normal to the curve?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2x+3y^2+3x^2y = 4x^2$

$2+6yy'+6xy+3x^2y'=8x$

$y' = \frac{8x-2-6xy}{6y+3x^2}$

$y'|_P = \frac{-8-2+6}{6+3} =\frac{-4}{9} $

> Slope of the normal at $P$,  $\ \ $ $m = -\frac{1}{y'} = +\frac{9}{4}$

So the equation of the normal to the curve at $P\equiv(-1,1)$ is,

$y - 1 = m(x-(-1))$

$y - 1 = \frac{9}{4}(x+1)$

$4y-4 = 9x + 9$

> $$9x-4y+13=0$$

Answer (score 0):

> $2+6y\frac{dy}{dx}+6xy+3x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=8x$
>
> $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{8x-2}{6y+6xy}$

That didn't go right, solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ gives:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{8x-2-6xy}{6y+3x^2}$$
which evaluates to $-\tfrac{4}{9}$ at $(-1,1)$.

---

> I just don't understand what they want me to do, "normal to the curve C at P?"

Now a **normal (line)** is *perpendicular* to the curve and thus to the tangent line, which means you want a slope corresponding to a line which is orthogonal to one with slope $-\tfrac{4}{9}$, that is $\tfrac{9}{4}$.

The problem is now reduced to setting up the equation of a line through the point $(-1,1)$ and with slope $\tfrac{9}{4}$:
$$y-1=\tfrac{9}{4}\left(x+1\right)$$